# Attempted to import .csv into mySQL using workbench, but only imports 6 rows?

Tags: mysql, csv, import-from-excel

To start, I'm still a relative SQL noob so this question could have an obvious answer that I'm just missing. I'm trying to start a big practice project in my spare time using the global terrorism database which is free to download. It has ~191000 rows and ~150 columns of data.

Attempting to use mySQLworkbench's table data import wizard to import the dataset after saving it as a .csv. When I run the import process, it successfully imports only 6 rows before giving this error:

"Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect integer value: ' January 10' for column 'INT_MISC' at row 1", 1366)"

I went back to the "configure import settings" screen to try modifying the datatype for column 'INT_MISC' but that column doesn't even appear in the list of source columns. That list only shows the first 32 columns. For the 6 rows that were successfully imported, though, all ~120 columns are present.

Is this error what is preventing more than 6 rows from importing? How do I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the input data!

Comment: I would look in row 7 for that value, the column name looks like a type and not a name. My guess is that that value should be 10 and not January 10. Find the column then change the import type to text so it is not validated

Comment: So, It looks like there are two distinct issues I'm experiencing. I tried deleting the problematic column from the source data just to see if the import worked correctly without it, but this time the import only pulled 7 rows. No error messages. The event log showed everything going smoothly...except it just didn't import the vast majority of the rows. Anyone know why that would be? I'll try the given solutions for fixing the error with the particular column.